# How to filter out "relevant" information from expression

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have an expression of the form

```
op = a3 b2 c1 d0 - a2 b3 c1 d0 - a3 b1 c2 d0 + a1 b3 c2 d0 + a2 b1 c3 d0 +...
```

that is, each term is of the form $a_i b_jc_kd_l$, where $i,j,k,l\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. I would like to define a linear function that takes `op` and does the following:
$$
\begin{align*}
P:
&\quad a_0\to a_0\\
&\quad a_k\to-a_k\\
&\quad b_0\to -b_0\\
&\quad b_k\to b_k\\
&\quad c_0\to c_0\\
&\quad c_k\to-c_k\\
&\quad d_0\to -d_0\\
&\quad d_k\to d_k.
\end{align*}
$$
As an example:
$$\begin{align*}
P(a_2 b_3 c_1 d_0+ a_0 b_3 c_2 d_1)&= (-a_2)b_3(-c_1)(-d_0)+a_0b_3(-c_2)d_1\\
&=-a_2 b_3 c_1 d_0-a_0b_3c_2d_1.
\end{align*}$$
My problem is that I don't know how to filter out the relevant information from a term, i.e. given `a3 b2 c1 d0` I would first need `{{a,3},{b,2},...}`. One could then define $P$ for a tupel `{ , }` via a switch statement or something like that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

What you want is greatly simplified if you use indexed variables. You can use [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) to display the output of indexed variables in any desired manner.

```
(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {a, b, c, d};

P[op_] := op /. {a[n_?Positive] :> -a[n], b[0] :> -b[0], 
   c[n_?Positive] :> -c[n], d[0] :> -d[0]}

op = a[3] b[2] c[1] d[0] - a[2] b[3] c[1] d[0] - a[3] b[1] c[2] d[0] + 
   a[1] b[3] c[2] d[0] + a[2] b[1] c[3] d[0];

P[op]
```

[image]

```
op2 = a[2] b[3] c[1] d[0] + a[0] b[3] c[2] d[1];

P[op2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have the input in indexed form... Is there a way to achieve this? The input is generated from vectors `a={a1,a1,a2,a3}, ...` using `LeviCivitaTensor` and `TensorContract`

Comment: @Sito you can write `aVec  = Array[a, {howeverManyTermsYouNeed}]` and then then do all the `LeviCevitaTensor`/`TensorContract` work with these vectors of indexed variables. Post-hoc, you can also do `expr /. s_Symbol?(StringMatchQ[SymbolName[#], ("a" | "b" | "c") ~~ NumberString] &) :> Symbol[StringTake[SymbolName[s], {1}]][ToExpression[StringDrop[SymbolName[s], {1}]]]`

Comment: `aVec = Array[a, 4, 0];` will start the index at `0`